# Specify column name in where (or) condition in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How to add or condition along with **source** column in below code.

Basically I am searching for a text in multiple columns. Below is the error being throws when **user.name** is included.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: \Unknown column 'flights.user.name' in 'where clause'
```

Below is the code.

```
const conditionObj = {
  [Op.or]: [
    {
      source: {
        [Op.like]: `%${text}%`
      }
    },
    {
      destination: {
        [Op.like]: `%${text}%`
      }
    },
    {
      "user.name": {
        [Op.like]: `%${text}%`
      }
    }
  ]
};

const list = await db.flights.findAndCountAll({
  where: conditionObj,
  attributes: [
    "id", "source", "destination"
  ],
  include: [
    {
      association: "user",
      attributes: ["id", "name", "mobile", "email"]
    },
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For associated models try to wrap field names with `$` like this:

```
{
  "$user.name$": {
    [Op.like]: `%${text}%`
  }
}
```

See the [Official documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#complex-where-clauses-at-the-top-level)